# CloudKit not working as intended with CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to setup CloudKit to enable automatic data syncing between the user's iCloud devices.

This is the code in my DataController file

```
...
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Stash")


init(){
container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
}
```

The data is successfully stored on the device locally, but I'm encountering the following error with CloudKit:

```
CloudKit setup failed because there is another instance of this persistent store actively syncing with CloudKit in this process.
```

How do I fix this? One of the threads on Reddit had a solution but they've gone private because of the strike and I couldn't find any solutions anywhere about this.

Comment: *…there is **another instance** of this persistent store* doesn’t ring a bell?